# Extract 'date sent' from email sent in Outlook and copied to the lead record

Tags: email, datetime, leads, outlook

We need to track first contact date/time and it's copied back to Salesforce from the Outlook connector and it's sent in Outlook.  I can see the date/time copied across, but it's not part of activities on the lead so I'm not sure how to query and use the data.  We have the Einstein activity capture setup.  I really doubt we're the only ones who want to track the exact time sent using this connector!

Any one have an idea?

[image: Example Email]